# Как преобразовать дату из формата daterangepicker (11/30/2019) в формат принимаемый объектом Date() (2019,11,30)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

Для расчета дней в периоде использую вот такую функцию

```
var Date1 = new Date(2019,01,01);
var Date2 = new Date(2020,01,01);

function GetAge (Date1, Date2){

  var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;    
  return Math.round(Math.abs((Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime())/(oneDay)));

}
```

Есть два поля (daterangepicker) с датами в формате (18/11/2019).
Как я могу преобразовать этот формат в формат принимаемый объектом `Date()` для отправки аргументов в функцию `GetAge()` и получения количества дней в периоде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, самый очевидный - через split

```
var date = '18/11/2019'
var arr = date.split('/')
var newDate = new Date(arr[2], arr[1] - 1, arr[0])
```

Comment: Да, не подумал бы преобразовать в массив), действительно самый простой способ, но может есть какая-нибудь функция которая это делает? Просто с JS совсем недавно начал работать, мало что знаю еще... Но спасибо! Новый участник, а так быстро ответили, хотя вопрос задан 2 часа назад)

Comment: Есть функция, но для этого надо поставить библиотеку наподобие https://momentjs.com/. Там это будет выглядеть примерно так                                                                                      var day = moment("18/11/2019", "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate()

Comment: Наверное обойдусь этим, итак слишком много библиотек подключено на страницу...

Comment: Хотя вот это очень удобно `moment().format('L');` все таки подключу библиотеку)